# I want to update each month's total sales on website but it is just updating the last sale made

Tags: php

I am creating an e-commerce website, in the admin dashboard, I want to show the total sales made in the particular month. So, I just fetched the sales according to the month and made a while loop to access each sale and an if else to check if the sales of a month are empty or not. But there is a problem, it is showing the last sale made ignoring the others.

```
<?php
    $thisYr = date("Y");
    $lastYr = $thisYr - 1;
    $thisYrQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE YEAR(txn_date) = '{$thisYr}'");
    $lastYrQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE YEAR(txn_date) = '{$lastYr}'");
    $current = array();
    $last = array();
    $currentTotal = 0;
    $lastTotal = 0;
    while ($x = mysqli_fetch_assoc($thisYrQ)) {
        $month = date("m",strtotime($x['txn_date']));
        if (!array_key_exists($month,$current)) {
            $current[(int)$month] = $x['grand_total'];
        } else{
            $current[(int)$month] += $x['grand_total'];
        }
        $currentTotal += $x['grand_total'];
    }

    while ($y = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lastYrQ)) {
        $month = date("m",strtotime($y['txn_date']));
        if (!array_key_exists($month,$current)) {
            $last[(int)$month] = $y['grand_total'];
        } else{
            $last[(int)$month] += $y['grand_total'];
        }
        $lastTotal += $y['grand_total'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're only interested in totals, let mysql do the job

```
SELECT SUM(grand_total) as grand_total, MONTH(txn_date) AS month FROM transactions WHERE YEAR(txn_date) = '{$thisYr}' GROUP BY MONTH(txn_date)
```

loop through the result & add it to data

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q) ) {
   $data[$row['month']] = $row['grand_total'];
}
```

then in your foreach loop you do the following

```
foreach (range(1, 12) as $month) {
   if ( exists($data[$month]) ){
       echo $data[$month];
   }else{
       echo "No data for month";
   }
```

This should be faster & takes less time/memory ...etc